# Every time I start my terminal, I get ".zshrc:source:18: no such file or directory: /sourceme.sh"?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

I've been trying to download some softwares. I've deleted those files, but now, I think my zsh file keeps wanting to source a file that's no longer there. Because of that, I get the following message every time I open up my terminal:

[image: zshrc:source17]

This is really annoying, and I'd like to get rid of it somehow... Thanks!

Comment: The error message names the file where the error occurs, and even the line number of the error. You want to remove the erroneous lines in a text file. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the following steps:

Open .zshrc and edit it. This can be done with the following:

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

From here, you may find a file, whatever it may be named (in this case, it was `sourceme.sh`). Delete the line that was installed in there. There are many reasons it's in there using nano. Then, save.

Where `sourceme.sh` came from: I downloaded another program that automatically wrote that line in when I configured it, and when I deleted, it could no longer find that file. It could be any other shell script (.sh).

Comment: Why `sudo` if you just want to edit your own file?

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me is the following:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-fails

Comment: See meta about link only answers as per meta SE

Comment: That is a super link. For you was it `nvm` or just that you ran `code` after having a command line shell successfully finish startup?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/322300)

Comment: @agarza You are quite right about that. How do I include the essential/relevant part? Should I upload a screenshot?

Comment: @bmike I used to open up VS code and the error would pop up every time, but I would ignore it because things used to run smoothly, even though this happened. Then I had an issue when I tried to use my terminal separate from VS code; I noticed that it would first run a process before I was able to use it. Then I went back to VS code and saw that error was there too.

Comment: Him- what we’re saying is, after you read that link, what did you do on your Mac specifically to resolve it. In case the link dies, etc…